# onCreateView() is not showing any data am taking from Database after calling it second time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I already searched every topic related to this but none of them helped me...
I am a beginner and I would really appreciate an answer...
When I launch the app it's all good but when I call HomeFragment for the second time problem is appearing.
I tried

`FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()`  to set right after 
    `fragmentTransaction.commit()` but it didn't help...

here is where I call a fragment from a menu
[image]

and here is my `onCreateView();` method in `HomeFragment` class

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: Add code and not an image of it. It's hard to read and hard to try in out own code.

Comment: add your code dont worry about editing, someone may reformat it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine. but the problem is that the volley request is executing Asynchronously in another thread. so your adapter is created with empty `bookTitle`.

so you need to set your adapter to the listView inside `onResponse()` after your books are ready.

you can also call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onResponse` to notify the adapter that your book has changed (no longer empty).

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot, and sorry for not posting a code and not just a picture... :)